# webkit div scrolling issue - asked over and over

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html, input, scroll

So, I have [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6VW2t/2/), as you will see, we have a scrollable `div` and a text `input` field as child.

The problem is this: the input box **must** stay inside container, but the div must NOT scroll when typing in.

I tried to catch `keypress` events and to scroll back, but it jumps around. Also, if you press `left-click` insite `input` and drag to the right, you will notice the div scrolling.

This question (and similar) had been asked before. No satisfactory answer until now. The only "fix" is to move the `input` outside the `div`. But, in my particular scenario, is not possible.

Any ideas ?

This happens only to Chrome (I suspect all webkit browser, but only tested in Chrome).

Comment: I am not seeing it, what version of chrome and OS?

Comment: Your markup has many, many invalid entries. You need to pay more attention to opening and closing tags, using `/` when making an `open-ended-tag` element (input, for example) and improper nesting.

Comment: improper nesting? like the input field inside scrolling div? I have to keep it like that. This one was over-simplified for testing purpose only, but the idea is a input inside a scrolling div, on the oposite side of the scrolling direction. And the div will somehow steal the focus and scroll towards input.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, once I cleaned up some of your markup and replaced `keyup keydown` with `keypress`, it's much smoother......

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/6VW2t/4/)

Comment: I'm using Win7 32bit and Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.41 m Aura. But your "cleaning" did nothing... only now it "stays" scrolled down, after I press a key. Not down-down, but... it descends a little. See this image: http://postimg.org/image/jchupoy05/ Using `keyup` and `keydown` I tried to force it back after typing. I was hoping it will happen instantly, so none will see the scrollbar jumping. I'm not satisfied with this partial scroll at all.